Get DLP Policies from compliance.microsoft.com
I am looking for powershell commands or a rest API to log in to compliance.microsoft.com and get all Data Loss Prevention (DLP) policies.
In the GUI I log into compliance.microsoft.com, navigate to Data loss prevention – Policies, check to see if there are any policies listed.
I found the powershell command 'Get-DlpCompliancePolicy' in my google search but cannot find what module it is in. I have ExchangeOnlineManagement 3.5. I thought it was supposed to be in there. It is not.
I logged into the GUI in Chrome and opened developer tools but was unable to find any graph endpoints for DLP policies. (I did this to get Intune policies and that worked well).
I just want to get a list of the polices, and get the locations for each policy (and loop thru 500 clients and do the same).
thanks

It's installed with ExchangeOnlineManagement. You'll want to use Connect-IPPSSession

Thanks .. finally got it ...
I can do this Get-DlpCompliancePolicy, output shows policy names but no locations. I also tried  Get-DlpCompliancePolicy | select * .. there's a lot more info .. but still no locations.

You can get all the policies using command
$dlpPolicies = Get-DlpCompliancePolicy which you have already done, but then iterate each policy and get details like this
$policy = Get-DlpCompliancePolicy "Policy Name" -DistributionDetail
$policy.SharePointLocation

I just gave an example of pulling the SharePoint sites location where policy is applied. Likewise you can pull other location info as well e.g. OneDrive, Teams etc.

Excellent, thank you!. This works.
